# Add include path to code model in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have a rather convoluted CMake project that I'm editing in Qt Creator. It compiles fine, but the Clang code model can't find some headers. It's not a bug - it's just because of how I am abusing CMake.

Anyway the question is: is there a way to manually add an include path to Qt Creator's code model?